# How & Where to create AIDL in android studio?

Tags: android, service, aidl

Now I am studying AIDL,

But I have no idea where to create AIDL?

I created AIDL file, but interface didn't automatically generate in gen folder (According to some of tutorials, it should be generated in That folder,'gen') I cant even find the folder.

please help me out! I am stuck in that first step!

Answer (score 1):

AIDL files needs to be placed under the directory /aidl/com/package/path/to/AidlFile.aidl.

For example, InAppBilling.aidl needs to be placed in /main/aidl/com/android/vending/billing/

Comment: Actually I did that, but I can't find the AIDL Java Interface automatically generated in gen folder after that. Please give me a guideline further.

Comment: @KyeongsikJasonKim clean the project it will be generated in gen folder